# Parallel execution of a function with goroutines and channels and deadlock error

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

Edit:: Full code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Gv60nzo3U3)

I have the following piece of code:

```
filelistchan := make(chan string)
for _, dir := range tld {
    w.Add(1)
    go GetFileList(dir, filelistchan, w)
}
for ;; {
    file, ok := <- filelistchan
    fmt.Println(ok)
    switch ok {
    case false:
        break
    default:
        fmt.Println(file)
    }
}
w.Wait()
```

and GetFileList function is

```
func GetFileList(dir string, filelistchan chan string, w sync.WaitGroup)  {
    defer fmt.Println("finishing from", dir)
    defer w.Done()
    fmt.Println("Searching in", dir)
    filelist := []string{}
    filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error{
    filelist = append(filelist, path)
    return nil
    })

    for _, file := range filelist {
        fmt.Println(file)
        filelistchan <- file
    }
}
```

I am calling `GetFileList` function parallely inside a forloop, to get the list of files inside them. It works fine till the last directory, however, once the last directory is completed, it gives an error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
```

and when I am printing the ok, I could see that false is never getting printed from the goroutine once it is finishing the job. I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I tried `close(filelistchan)` inside the `GetFileList` function, but it gives another error after the first goroutine exits, saying `write on closed channel` and `attempting to close a closed channel`. Can someone please explain, what is the best idiomatic way to get this working?

Comment: don't pass copies of waitgroups around, pass the pointer.  in this case, you are passing a copy which means wg.Done is called on the copy and not what the main function is waiting on, thus, you deadlock

Comment: Thank you, It is working now. If you could write it as an answer, I'll accept it.